# For a WPF AttachedProperty, can you validate the value based on the type you're attaching to?

Tags: wpf, validation, attached-properties

In short, we're creating an attached property that's only to be applied to `FrameworkElement` or one of its subclasses.  What we want is to block the set if it's being applied to anything that's not.

Now we can't use the `ValidateValueCallback` as that only gets passed the value of the property, not what you're attaching the property to.

Similarly, we can't use the `PropertyChangedCallback` because the value is already set at that point, and `NewValue` is read-only, and for some reason, we can't get `ClearValue` to 'stick' inside.

So... anyway to do what we want?

Answer (score 1):

Duh!  It wasn't `ValidateValueCallback`, it was `CoerceValueCallback` since that gives you the object!  Done and done!

**UPDATE**

Scratch that.  That's actually not 100% correct as I forgot about value precedence.

**[MSDN: Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx)**

In other words, it's still actually set, but it's just coerced back again to the default value, which means 'not set' in our case.  Damn.

I'm starting to think the only real way to do this here is to simply to throw an `InvalidOperationExcepton` in the `PropertyChangedCallback` but I'm not sure even that will 100% work as I believe the value has already been set once you're inside it.

I'll get back to you with a definitive.  Keep the answers coming!

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible -- but you do it in your Get and Set methods by controlling the type of the first parameter. If you want only FrameworkElements to be able to get or set the value then you only use framework elements in the get and set methods. This will prevent non-Framework elements from being able to set the value via XAML

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(...)

public static bool GetMyProperty(FrameworkElement e)
{
   return (bool)e.GetValue(MyPropertyProperty);
}
public static void SetMyProperty(FrameworkElement e, bool value)
{
   e.SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value);
```

}

Comment: That doesn't work. Well it partially does because it will block it from being set in XAML (it will throw an exception at runtime) you can still set it via code-behind since you can bypass CLR getter and setter. That's why you should never put any logic in those methods--there's no guarantee they will be used. They are just for convenience when calling directly from code, but can easily be bypassed by simply calling e.SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value) directly